# Pinging eBay API throws stringWithFormat error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ebay-api

I'm attempting to ping eBay's API using an HTTP request, however Xcode is giving me the following error

> No known class method for selector stringWithFormat

What I want to do here is append whatever string is input in the searchField to the end of the url. What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help!

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if (sender != self.nextButton) return;
    if (self.searchField.text.length > 0) {
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                 [NSURL stringWithFormat:@"http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=***APP ID ****&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value=FixedPrice&keywords=%@", self.searchField.text]];


        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }

}
```

Comment: `No known class method for selector stringWithFormat` Sorry about that!

Comment: Please read the fine message.  There is no `stringWithFormat` method for NSURL.

Comment: Ah ok. So how would I emulate that sort of functionality within an NSURL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create a `NSString` containing the URL and then create an `NSURL` out of it.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/",
    self.searchField.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: Gotcha. how would that work in terms of this part: 


`NSURL *searchFieldUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                 [NSURL *searchFieldUrl]];`



I'm getting an error stating `expected identifier` in regards to searchFieldUrl.

Comment: You don't need the `[NSURL *...]`, just write `searchFieldUrl` because it is already a `NSURL`: `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:searchFieldUrl]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=***APP ID ****&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value=FixedPrice&keywords=%@", self.searchField.text]]];
```

You were missing a step, NSURL does not have a method called stringWithFormat.